# Regex to match certain pattern unless part of larger pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex to find whenever there isn't a space after a period or comma, *unless* there are three periods in a row, in which case it's find to have another word character after.

E.g.

`"Hello.how are you"` -> **Match**

`"Sounds good..."` -> **No Match**

`"...are you sure?"` -> **No Match**

This is what I have so far (quotation marks after ., are fine too), but it finds a match for the third example, which I don't want.

```
/[.,][^\s"”.]/g
```

How can I specify that `\.\.\.\w` should not match, but any other `\.\w` should?

(Using js)

Comment: If using V8+ use lookbehind `(?<!\.)[,.][^\s"”.]`

Comment: Are you replacing? What is the expected output for the `Hello.how are you` string? If you replace with space, use `replace(/(\.{3}\w)|[.,](?![\s"”.])/g, function(x,y) { return y ? y : " "; })`

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels, that seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following regex does what you need:

```
(?<!\.\.)[.,](?=[^\s.])
```

It matches any period that isn't preceeded by two periods and that isn't followed by a period or a whitespace.

Comment: Thank you! Why do I need the positive lookahead?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to match. In this case I'm only matching the offending period or comma.